# How to add datapoints to a time series line plot to highlight events?

Tags: python, pandas, plotly, plotly-python

I am trying to add tweets as dot/scatter plots onto an existing plot via plotly.

Currently, my code is as follows:

```
fig = px.line(total_data, 
              x = 'date', y = ['doge_close','btc_close','eth_close','shib_close'], 
              color = 'has_tweet', hover_data = ['content', 'of_interest']
              )
fig.show()
```

Which produces the attached image here: [image: Plotly output]

What I'm looking to do is plot tweets on the line charts themselves, but as scatter plot points rather than the `has_tweet = 1` line. (added dots via photoshop) [image]

I can't find anything within the plotly python documentation, but have found some with R unfortunately, and `fig.add_trace` is fairly limited on what it can handle from inputs, so adding multiple axes doesn't help the cause.

Thank you for any help!

EDIT:

Thank you to a very kind commentor, I am almost there.

I have updated the code as such:

```
fig = px.line(total_data, x = total_data.date,
              y = total_data.doge_close)
fig.add_trace(
             go.Scatter(
                        x=total_data[total_data.has_tweet==1].date,
                        y=total_data[total_data.has_tweet == 1['doge_close'],
                         mode = 'markers',
                         name = 'Tweet',
                         hovertext = ['content', 'of_interest']))
fig.show()
```

However, hovertext is not displaying anything aside from `doge_price` and the date, when I'm trying to get it to display tweet content. Image with hover provided.

[image]

**EDIT #2**

```
fig = px.line(total_data, x = total_data.date,
                          y = total_data.doge_close)
fig.add_trace(
              go.Scatter(
                         x=total_data[total_data.has_tweet==1].date,
                         y=total_data[total_data.has_tweet == 1['doge_close'],
                         mode = 'markers',
                         hovertemplate = 
                                    '<i>tweet:</i>'+ '<br>' +
                                    
                                    '<i>%{text}</i>',
                                    
                                    text = [t for t in total_data['content'] != 'NaN'],
                                    name = 'has_tweets'))
fig.show()
```

The area giving me trouble is here: `text = [t for t in total_data['content'] != 'NaN']`
The `content` column is 7113 rows long, but only 139 rows have any content (tweets) in them. I tried identifying where it `!=  'NaN'`, and it seems to work, except logically, it's setting everything to true (which makes perfect sense in hindsight), and I cannot figure out how to bypass that.

See below: [image]

Comment: That last part is a bit hard to answer without a sample of your data. If my suggestions have helped you so far, would you consider asking that last part as a new question?

Comment: @vestland https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69920851/how-do-i-add-tweets-objects-to-a-plotly-chart-when-i-have-nans-in-the-datafra

I have continued it with a new question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I may be missing something here, but this should be as easy as adding a trace with `fig.add_trace(go.Scatter())` with values that correspond to your original values where some criteria is satisfied like this:

```
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df[df.has_tweet==1].index,
                         y = df[df.has_tweet==1]['values'],
                         mode = 'markers',
                        name = 'has_tweets'))
```

#### Plot 1 - Highlighted events

[image]

If you'd like to add more information to your highlghted events, you can do so through the `hovertemplate` and `text` attributes of `go.Scatter`

#### Plot 2 - Highlighted events with extra info in hovertemplate

[image]

#### Complete code for Plot 1:

```
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import random

df = px.data.stocks().set_index('date')[['GOOG']].rename(columns={'GOOG':'values'})
df['has_tweet'] = random.choices([0,1], weights=(90,10), k=len(df))

fig = px.line(df, x=df.index, y = 'values')
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df[df.has_tweet==1].index,
                         y = df[df.has_tweet==1]['values'],
                         mode = 'markers',
                        name = 'has_tweets'))
fig.show()
```

#### Complete code for Plot 2:

```
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import random

df = px.data.stocks().set_index('date')[['GOOG']].rename(columns={'GOOG':'values'})
df['has_tweet'] = random.choices([0,1], weights=(90,10), k=len(df))
df['tweet'] = random.choices(['A','B', 'C'], weights=(50,25,25), k=len(df))
df['tweet'].iloc[4] = "All the other tweets are short, <br> but this one is long"

fig = px.line(df, x=df.index, y = 'values')
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df[df.has_tweet==1].index,
                         y = df[df.has_tweet==1]['values'],
                         mode = 'markers',
                         hovertemplate =
                                        '<i>tweet:</i>'+ '<br>' +
                                        
                                        '<i>%{text}</i>',
                         text = [t for t in df['tweet']],
                         name = 'has_tweets'))
fig.show()
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm still learning plotly, so this is a huge help!

Comment: I should probably clarify that I want to get hover data from the points themselves, which is where I think I'm struggling with primarily, but this puts me on a good track.

Comment: @Falcon Both the line trace and the marker trace have hover data with this setup. Or would you like all red markers to have information showing regardless of hover?

Comment: I have updated the OP with a half-solution on what I'm trying to do, along with a screenshot of where I'm lost.

Comment: @Falcon I'm confused =) Have you edited *this* question after posting it? I can't see that in the editing history...

Comment: Whoops, I made changes on my desktop and didn't submit, then replied to your comment on my laptop. My apologies :)

Comment: @Falcon No problem. Fire away and let's see what to make of it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239058/discussion-between-falcon-and-vestland).