# How do I add tweets (objects) to a plotly chart when I have NaN's in the dataframe column?

Tags: python, pandas, plotly, plotly-python

I have a plotly chart that I am trying to add tweets to hover information.

The dataframe itself contains 7000+ rows (hourly crypto readings) and 139 tweets, labeled `content`. Of `content`, there are ~6861 rows of 'NaN' because `content` has 139 total tweets.

The code that I have below

```
fig = px.line(total_data, x = total_data.date,
                          y = total_data.doge_close)
fig.add_trace(
              go.Scatter(
                         x=total_data[total_data.has_tweet==1].date,
                         y=total_data[total_data.has_tweet == 1['doge_close'],
                         mode = 'markers',
                         hovertemplate = 
                                    '<i>tweet:</i>'+ '<br>' +
                                    
                                    '<i>%{text}</i>',
                                    
                                    text = [t for t in total_data['content']],
                                    name = 'has_tweets'))
fig.show()
```

produces this plot:

[image: Plotly_output_with_nan's]

Where it says `NaN`, I'd like the actual content of the tweets at that time.

The "content" column can be loosely reproduced with this code below:

```
df = px.data.stocks().set_index('date')[['GOOG']].rename(columns={'GOOG':'values'})
df['has_tweet'] = df['tweet'].apply(lambda x: 0 if x != x else 1)
df['tweet'] = random.choices(['A tweet','Longer tweet', 'emoji','NaN'], weights=(5,10,5,80), k=len(df))
```

and can be generically reproduced with the code below:

```
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import random

fig = px.line(df, x=df.index, y = 'values')
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df[df.has_tweet==1].index,
                     y = df[df.has_tweet==1]['values'],
                     mode = 'markers',
                     hovertemplate =
                                    '<i>tweet:</i>'+ '<br>' +
                                    
                                    '<i>%{text}</i>',
                     text = [t for t in df['tweet']],
                     name = 'has_tweets'))
fig.show()
```

Is there a way to filter out the 'NaN's from the dataframe in order to input the actual tweet content?

**EDIT WITH SOLUTION**

Thanks to a very kind commentor, I have figured out the solution and attached it below, for anyone in the future.

```
fig = px.line(total_data, x = total_data.date, y = total_data.doge_close)
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=total_data[total_data.has_tweet==1].date,
                     y=total_data[total_data.has_tweet==1]['doge_close'],
                     mode = 'markers',
                     hovertemplate = 
                                    '<i>tweet:</i>'+ '<br>' +
                                    
                                    '<i>%{text}</i>',
                                    
                                    text = [t for t in total_data.loc[total_data['has_tweet']==1, 'content']],
                                    name = 'has_tweets'))
fig.show()
```

which produces: [image]

Comment: I am a bit confused. Using your reproduction of the DataFrame, it seems like `df[df.has_tweet==1]` could still contain `NaN` for the `tweet` column. Is that correct?

Comment: Sorry, should have clarified it more and I don't think it was properly formulated since it could randomly assign has `has_tweet` = 1, but have `NaN` in the actual tweet content.

The real dataset has `has_tweet` paired with `content`, which would be an actual tweet. Functionally, if `has_tweet` == 1, `content` has an actual tweet, and not an NaN. 

Apologies for confusion.

Comment: No worries! I think `df['has_tweet'] = df['tweet'].apply(lambda x: 0 if x != x else 1)` will be consistent

Comment: @DerekO Yeah, that looks like it would work better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment, instead of randomly assigning 0 or 1 to the `"has_tweet"` column, it should be 0 or 1 based on whether the "tweet" column is `NaN` or not. Also instead of the string "NaN" I am using `np.nan`, but this may need to be modified depending on what your actual data looks like.

We can create some data similar to yours like this:

```
import numpy as np
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import random

random.seed(42)
df = px.data.stocks().set_index('date')[['GOOG']].rename(columns={'GOOG':'values'})
df['tweet'] = random.choices(['A tweet','Longer tweet', 'emoji',np.nan], weights=(5,10,5,80), k=len(df))
df['has_tweet'] = df['tweet'].apply(lambda x: 0 if x != x else 1)
```

Then I believe the only change we need to make is pass just the rows with tweets to the text argument:

```
fig = px.line(df, x=df.index, y = 'values')
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df[df.has_tweet==1].index,
                     y = df.loc[df.has_tweet==1]['values'],
                     mode = 'markers',
                     hovertemplate =
                                    '<i>tweet:</i>'+ '<br>' +
                                    
                                    '<i>%{text}</i>',
                     text = [t for t in df.loc[df.has_tweet==1, 'tweet']],
                     name = 'has_tweets'))
fig.show()
```

[image]